# How do I include other py files when using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have multiple py files, and all classes and methods defined in those files are being used and called in the main.py. My question is, how do I use pyinstaller to put everything inside one exe file, plus it knows that it needs to start with main.py
I tried to adjust the spec file and added these py files under "data" with full paths, but it was not working.

Let's say the code look like this

--file1.py

```
def simpleAdd(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

class SimpleClass:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
```

--main.py

```
from file1.py import *
num3 = simpleAdd(2, 3)
simpleClass = SimpleClass(num3)
```

-- __init __.py (empty)

Please... I am stuck over here...

Comment: You can use `--onefile` to make a single `exe` and you specify which file is your program's entry point, in this case `main.py`

Comment: I used command pyinstaller main.py -F, but it kept telling me that some modules could not be found

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'